# what is the dimension of this subspace for given problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

In a subspace $W=\{[a_{ij}]:a_{ij}=0$ if $i$ is even$\}$ of all $10\times 10$ real matrix, what is the dimension of W?

Comment: You might want to try a simpler version of the problem first. How about the subspace $\{[a_{ij}]: a_{ij}=0\mbox{ if $i$ is even}\}$ of the space of $4\times 4$ real matrices? See if you can write down a basis for this space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your space is the space of $10\times 10$ matrices with even lines equal to zeros. The dimension of $W$ is the number of non-zero variables of the matrix.

You can prove the last assertion by seeing that the matrices $(e_{ij})$ which contain $1$ on position $(i,j)$ and zero in the rest forms a basis for the matrix space.

Comment: Then you mean the dim of W is 50

Comment: Yes, you are right.